# How to find the rpc url for local private network on windows to connect to metamask?

Tags: metamask, rpc, private-ethereum

[image][image]    INFO [02-20|20:41:18.478] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://127.0.0.1:8551
INFO [02-20|20:41:18.478] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8551 auth=true prefix= cors=localhost vhosts=localhost

```
> admin.nodeInfo
{
  enode: "enode://69fe165f1360dbc709bb39f4f4553c0b9c2d83d05a50b8c4cf6acc48d28276de5801e7a556ba6bd03e44f1bc48888356d293141c8e1babde439febe7a840c1d1@127.0.0.1:30306",
  enr: "enr:-KO4QBP2z5qlXS6rf1hvY2t9bpZGSigiOkK96Tvf3j0gkjT7PTbl5vAPbeKd3uDNTXFN4Sfq4xB1c_OknALnPqjwotuGAY3Gzc3fg2V0aMfGhPxDpb6AgmlkgnY0gmlwhH8AAAGJc2VjcDI1NmsxoQNp_hZfE2Dbxwm7OfT0VTwLnC2D0FpQuMTPasxI0oJ23oRzbmFwwIN0Y3CCdmKDdWRwgnZi",
  id: "028dac93450f939bc3d75f14ac3a801561e68c5e01361b993a970e4f6a37d208",
  ip: "127.0.0.1",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30306",
  name: "Geth/v1.13.12-stable-02eb36af/windows-amd64/go1.21.6",
  ports: {
    discovery: 30306,
    listener: 30306
  },
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      config: {
        arrowGlacierBlock: 0,
        berlinBlock: 0,
        byzantiumBlock: 0,
        chainId: 7007,
        clique: {...},
        constantinopleBlock: 0,
        eip150Block: 0,
        eip155Block: 0,
        eip158Block: 0,
        grayGlacierBlock: 0,
        homesteadBlock: 0,
        istanbulBlock: 0,
        londonBlock: 0,
        muirGlacierBlock: 0,
        petersburgBlock: 0
      },
      difficulty: 4519,
      genesis: "0xe76aa0f8f05f787fdebd69e572a83980cb508abb7c86974676cab0239fd5725c",
      head: "0x0bcef0f3ea2d3272303f05f921695c76832dcc8d451b0f36129af7a12e13b2a1",
      network: 7007
    },
    snap: {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the values you provide, the RPC URL is as follows;

**http://127.0.0.1:8551**

In the output you provided, it is stated here;

> INFO [02-20|20:41:18.478] WebSocket enabled url=ws://127.0.0.1:8551 INFO [02-20|20:41:18.478] HTTP server started **endpoint=127.0.0.1:8551** auth=true prefix= cors=localhost vhosts=localhost

Comment: I used http://127.0.0.1:8551 and chain id 7007 but it did not work.
I also used  http://127.0.0.1:8545 as well, since it seemed to be the general suggestion.

Comment: According to the endpoint information you provided, the rpc url is "http://127.0.0.1:8551/"
Try adding a slash "/" at the end

Comment: I tried it as well. It doesn't work.

Comment: I got this issue solve with adding --syncmode full --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.api admin,eth,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3 --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain “*” --http.vhosts “*” --http.port 8545
Base on the article
https://medium.com/coinmonks/setup-geth-ethereum-private-network-3806ef7fbe42